# Strange outcomes for ring of integers in Sage

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, sagemath, discriminant

The number field is $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ with $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{24}$ and $f=x^4-24$. Now Sage tells me that $\Delta(f)=-2^{17}\cdot3^3$ and $\Delta_K:=\Delta(\mathscr{O}_K)=-2^{11}\cdot3^3$. By the formula $\Delta(f)=\left[\mathscr{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\right]^2\Delta_K$ we get that $\left[\mathscr{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\right]=8$.

However, if I ask Sage to compute the ring of integers of $K$, it returns that it's the maximal order in $\alpha$ with defining polynomial $f$, which means that $\mathscr{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ which contradicts that index which is $8$. What went wrong? Here's my code:

```
K.<a>=NumberField(x^4-24)      #define numberfield
K.polynomial().discriminant()  #compute disc(f)
K.discriminant()               #discriminant of ring of integers (or equivalently the field)
K.ring_of_integers()           #unexpected outcome for ring of integers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misinterpret the output of `K.ring_of_integers()`. It says:

```
Maximal Order in Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^4 - 24
```

It means:

```
Maximal Order in (Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^4 - 24)
```

or:

```
Maximal Order in K
```

It is just a name for the ring of integers; it does not give details about its structure.

What you probably wanted is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis:

```
sage: OK = K.ring_of_integers()
sage: OK.basis()
[1, a, 1/2*a^2, 1/4*a^3]
```

Indeed, it is not $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. You are right about the index of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$:

```
sage: O = K.order([a])
sage: O.index_in(OK)
8
```

Comment: Thanks, nice brief tutorial in Sage. So I can write $\mathscr{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\alpha^2/2,\alpha^3/4]$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The statement that $[1, \alpha, \alpha^2/2, \alpha^3/4]$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathcal{O}_K$ tells you a little "more", just like $[1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3]$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. That is, all elements are $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations of just these few (in the basis); you don't have to multiply and use relations as you would with a description like "$\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$".