# Calculations in a group ring with computer algebra system

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, computer-algebra-systems, group-rings

I am currently trying to read the paper *Constructions of difference sets* by Applebaum et al. Unfortunately, there are some very elaborate calculations. For example, in example 1.13 in the group ring $\mathbb{Z}K$
$$
(1+X+Y-XY)(1+X^2+Y^2+X^2Y^2)(1+X^3+Y^3-X^3Y^3),
$$
where $K=C_4^2=\langle X,Y \rangle$ is a product of cyclic groups. Is there a computer algebra system that can help me with this? I am not that familiar with it.

The result should be $4(1+X^2+Y^2+X^2Y^2)$.

Comment: So we just multiply out and can set $X^4=Y^4=1$?

Comment: Yes, $X^k = X^{k \mod 4}$

Comment: I know that SAGE can be used in-line. An example among many: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3503920.  I have seen GAP (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3475154) mentionned as well

Comment: For a less common CAS, you can try [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) even in your browser. The code `Z=(1 + X + Y - X*Y)*(1 + X^2 + Y^2 + X^2*Y^2)*(1 + X^3 + Y^3 - X^3*Y^3); lift(Mod(lift(Mod(Z, X^4-1)), Y^4-1))` gives  the expected answer.

Comment: Heraklit: I deleted my "answer", your comment was spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, multiplying out and taking the relations $X^4=Y^4=1$ we obtain
$$
4(X^2Y^2 + X^2 + Y^2 + 1)
$$
This can be computed with any CAS, and even by hand.
Examples of CAS are Maple, Mathematica, Singular, Gap, Reduce, Magma and many others. For a list see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems).

Comment: "Even by hand" is a bit strong? The product of the first and third terms is easily $4+XY(1-X^2-Y^2+X^2 Y^2)$ and $(1-X^2-Y^2+X^2 Y^2)$ easily kills $(1+X^2+Y^2+X^2 Y^2)$.